# Can't start WebHost in Xamarin macOS

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, xamarin, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to start WebHost in my Xamarin macOS:

```
            this.webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseUrls("https//*:8842")
                .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                .Build();
```

and when I'm running it:

```
this.webHost.Run();
```

TestStartup is empty:

```
    public class TestStartup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {

        }
    }
```

I'm receive error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
  at System.Console.add_CancelKeyPress (System.ConsoleCancelEventHandler value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/corlib/System/Console.cs:948 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.AttachCtrlcSigtermShutdown (System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim resetEvent, System.String shutdownMessage) [0x00031] in <127e718ac42e4542a71b54cec3ef156b>:0
```

and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm using example in this [article](https://www.koderdojo.com/blog/asp-net-core-web-api-on-macos-using-visual-studio-code).

Comment: The article you provided is to create an asp.net project, so the project you are creating now is asp.net project?

Comment: No, I'm need startup WebHost in Xamarin macOS application. Is it possible? I'm done this successfully on WPF application and need do same on Xamarin MacOS